# Postgres overlapping date ranges for view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables

```
    Table 1              Table 2             Table 3
   start_date          start_date          start_date
   end_date            end_date             end_date
    val                   val                  val
```

Now lets say I have the following in the tables:

```
Table 1
start_date    end_date     val
01-01-2000     31-01-2000   APPLE
01-02-2000                  ORANGE

table 2
start_date    end_date     val
01-01-2000     15-01-2000   TOMATO
16-01-2000                  LETTUCE

table 3
start_date    end_date     val
01-12-1999                  CAR
```

I want the above three tables put into a view with min/max dates.  Which would look like this:

```
start_date     end_date      val_table_1    val_table_2    val_table_3
01-12-1999     31-12-1999       null           null           CAR
01-01-2000     15-01-2000       APPLE          TOMATO         CAR
16-01-2000     31-01-2000       APPLE          LETTUCE        CAR
01-02-2000                      ORANGE         LETTUCE        CAR
```

Comment: What's your attempt so far?

Comment: see [SO isn't very welcoming, time for that to change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

Comment: @used-by-already I agree, I have been downvoted several times without any explanation. But at the same time it forces me as OP to ask better questions. And I am very thankful for every time I get free outstanding answers from professionals. By showing your attempts, it is easier to understand your question. So, welcome to SO! :-)

Comment: @sibert as the question isn't a common scenario, nor trivial to solve, I figured that I would offer a solution without some prior attempt. Also, I didn't much point in seeing a query that doesn't work. So, having read that blog thought I might as well proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the wanted result with the query below. Also available as a demo here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/64042/1). Leave out the final `order by` clause if creating a view, it was included here just to present the results sensibly.

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("start_date" timestamp, "end_date" timestamp, "val" varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("start_date", "end_date", "val")
VALUES
    ('2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-31', 'APPLE'),
    ('2000-02-01 00:00:00', NULL, 'ORANGE')
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ("start_date" timestamp, "end_date" timestamp, "val" varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ("start_date", "end_date", "val")
VALUES
    ('2000-01-01', '2000-01-15', 'TOMATO'),
    ('2000-01-16', NULL, 'LETTUCE')
;

CREATE TABLE Table3
    ("start_date" timestamp, "end_date" timestamp, "val" varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Table3
    ("start_date", "end_date", "val")
VALUES
    ('1999-01-12 00:00:00', NULL, 'CAR')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with ends as (
          select end_date from Table1 where end_date is not null union
          select end_date from Table2 where end_date is not null union
          select end_date from Table3 where end_date is not null
          )
select
       d.start_date
     , least(e.end_date, lead(d.start_date,1) over(order by d.start_date) - INTERVAL '1 DAY') as end_date
     , table1.val as t1_val
     , table2.val as t2_val
     , table3.val as t3_val
from (
    select start_date from Table1 union
    select start_date from Table2 union
    select start_date from Table3
    ) d
left join lateral (
  select ends.end_date from ends where ends.end_date > d.start_date
  order by end_date
  limit 1
  ) e on true
left join table1 on d.start_date between table1.start_date and coalesce(table1.end_date,current_date)
left join table2 on d.start_date between table2.start_date and coalesce(table2.end_date,current_date)
left join table3 on d.start_date between table3.start_date and coalesce(table3.end_date,current_date)
order by
       start_date, end_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/64042/1/0)**:

```
|           start_date |             end_date | t1_val |  t2_val | t3_val |
|----------------------|----------------------|--------|---------|--------|
| 1999-01-12T00:00:00Z | 1999-12-31T00:00:00Z | (null) |  (null) |    CAR |
| 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2000-01-15T00:00:00Z |  APPLE |  TOMATO |    CAR |
| 2000-01-16T00:00:00Z | 2000-01-31T00:00:00Z |  APPLE | LETTUCE |    CAR |
| 2000-02-01T00:00:00Z |               (null) | ORANGE | LETTUCE |    CAR |
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  However, when I modify it to suit my actual tables, all my end_dates are 1 day less than the start dates.   Do you have any idea how/why that would be?

Comment: Oh and by the way, I have created a new question as what i had asked was a little too basic for what I need..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306431/postgres-overlapping-date-ranges-for-view-more-complex

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is more complicated than it need be.

```
with t as (
      select start_date as dte, val as val1, null as val2, null as val3 from table1
      union all
      select start_date as dte, null as val1, val as val2, null as val3 from table2
      union all
      select start_date as dte, null as val1, null as val2, val as val3 from table3
     ),
     tt as (  -- eliminate duplicates
      select dte, max(val1) as val1, max(val2) as val2, max(val3) as val3
      from t
     )
select dte as start_date,
       lead(dte) over (order by dte) - interval '1 day' as end_date,
       coalesce(val1,
                first_value(val1) over (order by (val1 is not null)::int desc, dte desc)
               ) as val1,
       coalesce(val2,
                first_value(val2) over (order by (val2 is not null)::int desc, dte desc)
               ) as val2,
       coalesce(val3,
                first_value(val3) over (order by (val3 is not null)::int desc, dte desc)
               ) as val3
from tt
order by start_date;
```

This is using some a key observation from the data:  the time frames are "tiled" within each table.  They do not overlap and they do not have gaps.  For the purposes of this version, the values are also not-`NULL` (handling `NULL` values just makes the query look a bit more complicated but the logic is the same).  If you need help with that, then please ask *another* question.

How does this work?

- `t` shows what happens in each table at each `start_date`.
- `tt` handles duplicates on a given date.  This provides each row of the result table.
- Finally, what you really want is `lag(ignore nulls)`, but Postgres does not support it.  Instead this uses a `first_value()` equivalent.

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/VLDAOE62107).

Comment: Thank you for that.  You wouldn't be able to help me with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306431/postgres-overlapping-date-ranges-for-view-more-complex  it is basically the same question but what I actually need is a little more complex...  I didnt ask this question well enough but it has been answered so well I thoujght I would just create a new one

Comment: For subquery `tt` line `group by dte` is missing in the answer above (but is present in the rextester link) and the results at rextester don't match the results presented in the question (see NULLs in first row)